# OS Upgrade and Xcode Options for Mac mini

Tags: macos, xcode, upgrade, mac-mini

Got my first Mac, a Mac mini, that runs Yosemite. I wish to create apps for iOS including iOS 10 but looks like I need the latest version of Xcode for that (8.1) and Yosemite only seems to support 7.1.1.

I tried downloading and updating to macOS Sierra which didn't work, just installed Yosemite again.

Would apps built in Xcode 7.1.1 still run on the latest iPhone running iOS 10+?
Is there an El Capitan upgrade available in App Store, couldn't see one?

It a Late 2014 Mac mini with:

- 1.4GHz dual-core i5
- 4GB of RAM
- Intel HD Graphics 5000
- 500GB hard drive

Purchased from: [http://www.currys.co.uk/...](http://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/computing/desktop-pcs/desktop-pcs/apple-mac-mini-10081070-pdt.html)

Comment: Instead of finding workarounds to run Xcode 8.x on Yosemite it would be easier to solve the issues preventing you from upgrading to Sierra. What exactly "didn't work"?

Comment: I looked at the Specification tab at the link you purchased it from and it didn't state what model year the Mac mini was however the only Mac mini with a 1.4 GHz CPU is the Mac mini Late 2014 and it supports macOS Sierra. So, have you downloaded the _Install macOS Sierra.app_ application bundle, force quit the installer and then created a macOS Sierra USB Installer and tried doing _clean install_ not an _in-place upgrade_?

Comment: The version/bcode is 
MPN: MGEM2B/A EAN: 885909954551    I just downloaded MacOSX Sierra from the App Store and then installed. When I came back it had the final setup steps for Yosemite, so i assumed incompatible and it reverted back to Yosemite. Just followed this http://www.imore.com/how-to-download-macos

Answer (score -2):

There's a very messy way of getting Xcode 7 to work with iOS 10 which can be found via the link I've left below.

Apple seem to have taken away the option to purchase (free Purchase) El Capitan from the Mac App Store, if you've bought it in the past or know someone who has then they can re-download it again as it will be listed in the purchased section of the Mac App Store. 
Installing El Capitan will allow you to tun Xcode 8 since you can't install macOS Sierra

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945376/use-xcode-7-with-ios-10